# angular route fragment replacing complete URL path

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to utilize the angular 9 route fragment for nav tabs using ng-bootstrap and referred this [ng-bootstrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview#routing). The problem is on adding click tab it's replacing the whole URL path e.g. path should be like https://www.mypleaks.com/home#International after clicking tab but it is forming https://www.mypleaks.com/#International, it is completely replacing /home path

[stackblitz view link](https://desh-angular-fragment.stackblitz.io/home) and [stackblitz edit link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/desh-angular-fragment)

HTML

```
<ul ngbNav [activeId]="route.fragment | async" class="nav-tabs justify-content-center container-lg">
    <li [ngbNavItem]="flatTab.name" *ngFor="let flatTab of flatTabs">
        <a ngbNavLink routerLink="." [fragment]="flatTab.name"
        [class.active]="flatTab.active" (click)="activateTab(flatTab)">{{ flatTab.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { TabService } from '../../services/tab.service';
import { FlatTab } from '../../modals/flat/flat-tab';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.scss']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public flatTabs : FlatTab[];
  constructor(public tabService: TabService, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tabService.getTabs().subscribe(resp => {
      this.flatTabs = { ...resp.body }.flatTabs;
      this.route.fragment.subscribe((name: string)=>{
        let isActiveSet = false;
        this.flatTabs.forEach(flatTab => {
          if(name == flatTab.name){
            flatTab.active = true;
          }else{
            flatTab.active = false;
          }
          if (!name && !isActiveSet) {
            isActiveSet = true;
            flatTab.active = true;
          }else if (!name && isActiveSet) {
            flatTab.active = false;
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

FlatTab

```
export class FlatTab {
    tabId: number;
    name: string;
    active: boolean;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You app-routing.module.ts should have code below :-**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Your home.component.html should have code below :-**

```
<ul ngbNav [activeId]="route.fragment | async" class="nav-tabs justify-content-center container-lg">
    <li [ngbNavItem]="flatTab.name" *ngFor="let flatTab of flatTabs">
        <a ngbNavLink routerLink="home" [fragment]="flatTab.name"
         [class.active]="flatTab.active" (click)="activateTab(flatTab)">{{ flatTab.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Working stackblitz below :-**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/desh-angular-fragment-x3kj4w

Comment: Hi Akash, thanks for reply. As per documentation(https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview#routing) it should be "."(I have updated the question as well) but I tired both but its not working.

Comment: stackblitz please?

Comment: give stackblitz then only i can help

Comment: I'm configuring it.

Comment: Aakash this is the edit URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/desh-angular-fragment
and you must navigate '/home' like https://desh-angular-fragment.stackblitz.io/home 
its a route configuration issue where i'm able to understand how to handle fragments in the URL

Comment: you want that as soon as you launch  stackblitz.com/edit/desh-angular-fragment it should go to desh-angular-fragment.stackblitz.io/home  ?

Comment: updated solution above, please vote if it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214517/discussion-between-raj-bhatia-and-aakash-garg).